# Can Only Access One Class Variable from Checkbox Event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, events

I'm sure this is a rookie error so forgive me since I'm new (this week) to AngularJS.

I've got an input which is a checkbox like below and it's hooked up to an ng-change event.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.hasCondoKey" ng-change="vm.onKeyCheckboxChange()" />
```

That^ event fires and runs the function "onKeyCheckBoxChange" in the controller.

```
export class CondoKeyController {

    public condoKey: AdditionalItemModel;
    public additionalItems: AdditionalItemModel[];
    public hasCondoKey: boolean = false;

    static $inject = ["$scope","CondoKeyService"];

    constructor($scope: any, CondoKeyService: ICondoKeyService) {

        $scope.additionalItems.forEach((addOn: AdditionalItemModel, index: number, addOnArray: AdditionalItemModel[]) => {

            if (addOn.typeId === Models.AdditionalItemType.CONDO_KEY && addOn.quantity > 0) {
                this.condoKey = addOn;
                this.hasCondoKey = true;
            }
        });
    }

    public onKeyCheckboxChange(): void {
        console.log("Checkbox changed.");
        if(this.hasCondoKey === true) {
            this.condoKey.typeId = AdditionalItemType.CONDO_KEY;
            this.condoKey.quantity = 1;

            if(!this.addOnsContainCondoKey()) {
                this.additionalItems.push(_this.condoKey);
            }
        } else {
            this.condoKey.quantity = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The "CondoKeyController" is nested in a parent which passes the array "additionalItems" to this controller via a directive. I can see these other variables in other functions and when constructing the controller so they make it into this controller fine.

**My problem is that in the function "onKeyCheckBoxChange" I can access "this.hasCondoKey" but I cannot access any of the other values such as "this.condoKey" or "this.additionalItems".**

I was thinking that this had to do with the scope and context of my function since it came from a checkbox event but then I reasoned that I should not have access to the "this.hasCondoKey" value. This value reads as "true" from my breakpoints so it's been changed from its initialization value.

Does anyone know why I can access some variables and not others? Also how do I access the other variables?

Angularjs 1.6.6
Typescript ~2.3.1

Comment: Does the logging those 2 fields inside the method show anything? Can you explain what do you mean by "I cannot access any of the other values"? Are you getting exception? Compile errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some debug helping log to the method:

```
public onKeyCheckboxChange(): void {
        console.log("Checkbox changed.");
        console.log(this.condoKey);
        console.log(this.additionalItems);
        // ...
}
```

Check the result. It could be possible that `condoKey` and `additionalItems` are undefined, meaning they are never set.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tadija, I'll add that logging. I would like to point out that there is a note in the post explaining that the initialization has been confirmed in the constructor through breakpoints --> It's a long post so that is hard to pick out, sorry about that.

Comment: Actually figured this out with your help Tadija. I was absent minded when adding the "&& addOn.quantity > 0". This was setting in a lot of cases but not a few. Sorry to bother you with that...this is what happens when I code without coffee...

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck and keep that coffee near by!